# Limiting a selection with multiple includes using Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, frameworks, entity

I have the following code that successfully loads a complete set of entities from my database. I am having difficulty limiting this selection to records where a field in the submissions table is set to a specific value. Note the submissions is a collection contained within a collection of batches.

```
                Dim pl As List(Of BATCH) = db.BATCHes _
                .Include("HEADER") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.SUB_HEADER") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL.MA_CUR_EMP") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL.MA_CON") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL.MA_CAD") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL.MA_TEL") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL.MA_EMA") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL.MA_BNK") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL.MA_BNK.MA_BWA_RES") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MA_POL.MA_DOC") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.VEH") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.VEH.VEH_GAR_ADD") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MAIN_DRI") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_CAD") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_TEL") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_EMA") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_DOC") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_CON") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.ADD_DRI") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_CAD") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_TEL") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_EMA") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_DOC") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_CON") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.BRO") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.DEV") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.DEV.DEV_IP") _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.DEV.DEV_PIP") _
                .ToList
```

I have tried adding a where clause but because the submissions collection is not the top-level, this is not working as intended.

```
 .Where(Function(y) y.SUBMISSIONS.Select(Function(y) y.XMLBatchNumber = BatchNumber).ToList
```

This causes a syntax error.

If I add similar code to the .Include statement for submission, I get no syntax error, but the code throws an error when executed.

```
    Dim pl As List(Of BATCH) = db.BATCHes _
                .Include("HEADER") _
                .Include(Function(x) x.SUBMISSIONS.Select(Function(y) y.XMLBatchNumber = BatchNumber)) _
                .Include("SUBMISSIONS.SUB_HEADER") _' Etc...
```

The error is: '{"The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties." & vbCrLf & "Parameter name: path"}'

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: You are missing a `)` somewhere... look carefully and count the number of `(` and `)`

Answer (score 0):

For using `Include` you need to expose the class property you are looking for as a navigation property of your entity, i.e. `Public Property Submissions as ICollection(Of Submission)`

In your case you have a Batch entity, which should expose a Collection of Submission entities as a navigation property. This way you can load it using `Include.`

If you dont want to have this navigation properties, you can use `Joins` to get the data you are looking for, without using `Include`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions they helped me arrive at a solution.

I was able to fix the issue by splitting my selection up as shown below:

```
 db.BATCHes.Load
 db.SUBMISSIONs.Include("SUB_HEADER") _
                        .Include("MA_POL") _
                        .Include("MA_POL.MA_CUR_EMP") _
                        .Include("MA_POL.MA_CON") _
                        .Include("MA_POL.MA_CAD") _
                        .Include("MA_POL.MA_TEL") _
                        .Include("MA_POL.MA_EMA") _
                        .Include("MA_POL.MA_BNK") _
                        .Include("MA_POL.MA_BNK.MA_BWA_RES") _
                        .Include("MA_POL.MA_DOC") _
                        .Include("VEH") _
                        .Include("VEH.VEH_GAR_ADD") _
                        .Include("MAIN_DRI") _
                        .Include("MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_CAD") _
                        .Include("MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_TEL") _
                        .Include("MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_EMA") _
                        .Include("MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_DOC") _
                        .Include("MAIN_DRI.MAIN_DRI_CON") _
                        .Include("ADD_DRI") _
                        .Include("ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_CAD") _
                        .Include("ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_TEL") _
                        .Include("ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_EMA") _
                        .Include("ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_DOC") _
                        .Include("ADD_DRI.ADD_DRI_CON") _
                        .Include("BRO") _
                        .Include("DEV") _
                        .Include("DEV.DEV_IP") _
                        .Include("DEV.DEV_PIP") _
                        .Where(Function(s) s.XMLBatchNumber = BatchNumber).Load
```